# error uploading theme using shopify_theme gem on Windows

Tags: ruby, shopify

I'm getting the following error when trying to upload theme files to shopify using the gem:

```
C:\Users\will\workspace\theme\Timber>theme upload                                                                                                                                    
[14:00:45] Uploading: assets/ajax-cart.js.liquidC:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in 
`connect': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (Ope
nSSL::SSL::SSLError)                                                                                                                                                                 
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'                                                                                                          
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'                                                                                                                     
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'                                                                                                                   
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'                                                                                                                  
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'                                                                                                                     
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'                                                                                                                  
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5/lib/httparty/request.rb:101:in `perform'                                                                             
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5/lib/httparty.rb:522:in `perform_request'                                                                             
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5/lib/httparty.rb:486:in `put'                                                                                         
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.22/lib/shopify_theme.rb:71:in `send_asset'                                                                         
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.22/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:234:in `block in send_asset'                                                           
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.22/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:297:in `show_during'                                                                   
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.22/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:233:in `send_asset'                                                                    
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.22/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:106:in `block in upload'                                                               
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.22/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:105:in `each'                                                                          
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.22/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:105:in `upload'                                                                        
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'                                                                                          
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'                                                                           
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'                                                                                            
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'                                                                                          
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.22/bin/theme:25:in `<top (required)>'                                                                              
from C:/Ruby21/bin/theme:23:in `load'                                                                                                                                        
from C:/Ruby21/bin/theme:23:in `<main>'
```

It seems to be an SSL error but I installed the SSL certificate and made the environment variable as per the instructions at http://shopify.github.io/shopify_theme/.